# Moving logic from Template Toolkit to Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class, template-toolkit

I think that I am using too much conditionals and calculations in the TT templates.

I am displaying a result set of items from DBIc. For each item I need to calculate things using the retrieved values, and the template doesn't seems to be the right place.

But in Catalyst it is a thick object that comes from DBIc.

So how can I move logic to the model? Must I run a whole loop for all items and change the object somehow?

Regards:
Migue,

Comment: **Thank you all.** By instinct I have started to create models in critical points, so I have "things to call" from the controller, and the controller calls the database and makes its calculations.

As I am learning, I am sure that I will improve the models from inside, but I will still call them the same way, making easy the refactoring process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you're on the right track by wanting to properly separate concerns. You'll thank yourself if you're the maintainer 6-12 months down the road.

IMHO, your Catalyst controllers should be as thin as possible with the business logic in the various models. This makes it easier to test because you don't have the overhead of Catalyst to deal with. I've been thinking about model separation quite a bit myself. There are two schools of thought I've come across:

1) Make your DBIx::Class Result classes have the business logic. This approach is convenient and simple.

2) Make a standalone Model which is instantiated by the Controller, and which has a DBIx::Class schema object. The model would use the DBIC schema to query the database, and then use the resulting data in its own business logic methods. This approach might be better if you have a lot of business logic since you separate DB access from business logic.

Personally, I've historically used approach #1 but I'm leaning towards #2 for larger apps.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities.

1. Create a method in corresponding schema class.
2. (if 1 is not possible) Pass a callback to template that would have this object as argument.

Comment: The first one seems similar to [link](http://search.cpan.org/~arodland/DBIx-Class-0.08196/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#OVERLOADING_METHODS) but not sure, and I do not know how to call it from the result set where the query is done. If this is not the way I would appreciate a tutorial or doc.

Comment: call it as $row->some_method(). You will need to define some_method() in schema.

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. create a resultset that retrieves the data from the database and then calculates the needed values
2. if possible calculate the needed values within the database and then only retrieve the data needed for output

I personally would prefer the second one.
I hope that helps.